# How to add inline css to the Transaction Emails

Tags: magento2, php, email, css, header

I need to update existing email header. There for I have to modify some styles.but doesn't define in specific style in app/design/frontend/{themename}/{namespace}/Magento_Email/email/header.html

**app/design/frontend/{themename}/{namespace}/Magento_Email/email/header.html**

```
 <!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<!--@subject Header @-->
<!--@vars {
"var logo_height":"Email Logo Image Height",
"var logo_width":"Email Logo Image Width",
"var template_styles|raw":"Template CSS"
} @-->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <style type="text/css">
        {{var template_styles|raw}}

        {{css file="css/email.css"}}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
{{inlinecss file="css/email-inline.css"}}

<!-- Begin wrapper table -->
<table class="wrapper" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td class="wrapper-inner" align="center">
            <table class="main" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td class="header">
                        <a class="logo" href="{{store url=""}}">
                            <img
                                {{if logo_width}}
                                    width="{{var logo_width}}"
                                {{else}}
                                    width="180"
                                {{/if}}

                                {{if logo_height}}
                                    height="{{var logo_height}}"
                                {{else}}
                                    height="52"
                                {{/if}}

                                src="{{var logo_url}}"
                                alt="{{var logo_alt}}"
                                border="0"
                            />
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="main-content">
                    <!-- Begin Content -->
```

but after preview the Email template in admin panel it show as below.
Check below image

[image]

I need to change background color and padding and width of the highlighted element `(<td>)`

How change the style in element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add your css in _email.less file. Below is the file path.

```
app/design/frontend/{themename}/{namespace}/web/css/source/_email.less
```

If _email.less is not exists on this file then copy it from the parent theme.